\documentclass in separate .tex file
I have always put all my preamble, including \documentclass, in a separate "preamble.tex" file like this:
\documentclass[a4paper,
    twoside=on,
    titlepage=on,   
    11pt,
    BCOR=1cm,
    DIV=calc]
    {scrartcl}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, italian]{babel}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc}

and then input it in the "main.tex" like this:
\input{preamble.tex}

\begin{document}

Text here.

\end{document}

and it always worked without problems.
Now I was reading some articles and posts about large multi file documents and in many places I found that a file imported with \input{file.tex} "should not contain any LaTeX preamble code (i.e. no \documentclass, ...)".
So where is the downside of including the \documentclass in a separate file?

That is not what the article is talking about. That problem is for file you input in the body of your document. They either should not contain doc class or preamble, or you should use tools that will ignire them. Your setup is fine

Welcome to TeX.SX! “Now I was reading some articles and posts” is somehow vague. It does neither tell us which article you read, what exactly they tell, even not where you read them. So if you refer to articles or posts, please always link them. Preferably, you should also summarize the question of the article and its arguments in such a way that they remain reasonably comprehensible even without the links. Otherwise, it is unfortunately only possible to respond to unknown articles in a completely speculative manner. If I had to guess, I would fully agree with daleif's interpretation.

Another guess: The articles are about using Overleaf. AFAIK overleaf automatically guesses that the file with \documentclass is the main file. So doing the opposite (which means: writing a main file with the document class, the preamble and a body that just inputs either the whole content at once or the single chapters one by one) could be easier using overleaf.

Thank you @carbohah, your guess is right, one of the articles was "Management in a large project" from the Overleaf documentation, so probably it refers only to Overleaf. I don't remember the other posts, I read it in the last days and din not take notice...

I would always put at least the class into the main document. I find that clearer and it also confuse less editors like overleaf  that parse the code to identify the main file.


Now I was reading some articles and posts about large multi file documents and in many places I found that a file imported with \input{file.tex} "should not contain any LaTeX preamble code (i.e. no \documentclass, ...)".

That would have been describing a different situation, where individual chapters or sections are all \input into a master document. If the individual files have \documentclass then your main document has multiple \doumentclass which will give LaTeX errors and most likely no output.
The situation you show is not a TeX error, and as far as LaTeX is concerned it's a perfectly normal style however I would say it is better practice to put at least the \documentclass line into your main file.  If running latex "by hand" on the commandline you know that main.tex is your main file and preamble.tex is input so would run pdflatex main not pdflatex preamble however Editors and document build systems are not so knowledgable. If you hit "run" or whatever the button or menu option is, while a file in your project is open, the system needs to know whch is the main file. For many systems (notably Overleaf) if your main file starts \documentclass it will guess right and use that file, but if \documentclass is in an input file as you show it will guess wrong. That is not a major problem, there is a menu setting in the sidebar to specify the main file if the automatic guess is wrong, but it's just one more step to remember.

Thank you @DavidCarlisle, now I see the difference. I normally put the documentclass in preamble.tex so, by choosing which preamble to use, I can set the document type (e.g. theory, exercise, test...) but I use a makefile to compile, so it works. In my mind I thought that the editor would guess that the main file is the one with \begin{document}.
